# How Deep Probabilistic (Graphical) Models differs from the usual Probabilistic Graphical Models?

Tags: deep-learning, graphical-model, probabilistic-programming

How Deep Probabilistic (Graphical) Models differs from the usual Probabilistic Graphical Models? What are the main applications and state of art results of Deep Probabilistic Models?

Comment: Where can I learn deep probabilistic graphical models? I search the Google and find nothing about it.

Comment: Hi lerner , please take a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06458